# Are there any advanced clipboard managers for Linux?

Tags: software-rec, x11, clipboard

Are there any "advanced clipboard" managers for Linux that can store several things at one time?

For example I might wnat to collect several things in the clipboard:

- a .jpg file
- some text
- etc.

Then when I press (for example) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> just the first "thing" would be pasted. (In this example the .jpg file) If I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>, then it pastes the text, etc.

Are there any clipboard manager that support such "layers"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to check out [Parcellite](http://parcellite.sourceforge.net/). It is described as:

> A lightweight GTK+
>   clipboard manager. This is a stripped
>   down, basic-features-only clipboard
>   manager with a small memory footprint
>   for those who like simplicity.

Even though it is described as "stripped down, basic-features-only" it has very useful features, such as:

- Keeps a clipboard history (which is completely editable).
- Various view options to display items the way you like it.
- Daemon mode; guard your clipboard contents when you close applications.
- Global hotkeys to display your items quickly.
- Perform custom commands using clipboard contents.
- Syncs the CLIPBOARD and PRIMARY selections.

Here are a couple articles which go into more detail:

- http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/455090-hone-your-desktop-clipboards-with-parcellite-on-linux
- http://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/parcellite-is-lightweight-clipboard-manager-for-ubuntu-linux/

Answer (score 5):

Yet another option is [ClipIt](http://clipit.rspwn.com/):

> ClipIt is a lightweight, fully featured GTK+ clipboard manager. It was
>   forked from [Parcellite](http://parcellite.sourceforge.net/), adding additional features and bugfixes to the
>   project.
>
> ClipIts main features are:
>
> - Save a history of your last copied items
> - Search through the history
> - Global hotkeys for most used functions
> - Execute actions with clipboard items
> - Exclude specific items from history

Answer (score 2):

```
glipper - Clipboard manager for the GNOME panel
klipper - clipboard utility for KDE 4
```

To find such programs by keyword on your own:

```
apropos clipboard 
apt-cache search clipboard
```

The first is for already installed programs, the second for installable ones.

If you prefer GUIs: In Ubuntu, you can use Synaptics, and there is a search-field, where you can search for 'name and description'. I guess fedora has a similar thing for RPMs.

Answer (score 1):

[Keepboard](http://sourceforge.net/projects/keepboard/) offers similar functionality. It is described as:

> Keepboard is a cross-platform clipboard manager. It supports saved items groups and adding names to items for quicker filtering and selection. It can save text and image clipboard items (up to 2000 per group). The current version supports Linux (GNOME, KDE...) and Windows platforms.