# How to use keyboard instead of mouse middle-click for copy/paste?

Tags: x11, copy-paste

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Pasting X selection (not clipboard contents) with keyboard](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11889/pasting-x-selection-not-clipboard-contents-with-keyboard)

Is there a shortcut for copy-paste under X? I'd like to use the keyboard for pasting.

Answer (score 22):

In graphical terminals, you can try <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> instead of <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.

As an alternative, you can try <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>INSERT</kbd> or <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>INSERT</kbd>. To copy a word with insert, you can use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>INSERT</kbd> The first one will paste the last highlighted word, and the second the last copied one.

They won't work everywhere, unfortunately, but it's a good start. You must be aware than in most cases, the best option will be <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.

Note that these combinations may have to be mixed to work for different applications... For instance, on KDE, I have to use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy from a Konsole, and then <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste in Firefox/Kate... or most of applications that are not a terminal. The key is that <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> CAN'T be used to copy from the terminal, as it is a way to send a signal to the current running process in it... I've tested the combinations with <kbd>INSERT</kbd> with Konsole, too. One of them (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>INSERT</kbd>) does not work with NetBeans... Consequently, I'm not sure how to emulate the middle click behaviour from the keyboard...

Comment: none of these work, to paste the selection (which I did not copy! just selected...)

Comment: I got it.

For X I was used to select and paste -- without copying.

In gnome-terminal I can use CTRL+SHIFT+C to copy to clipboard. Then the contents are available in other apps.

Select-and-paste seems to be a different approach, which works only in a terminal. please clarify if you know more about this.

Comment: X does have two different systems: a select buffer and a cliboard. However I can select in Gnome-terminal and paste into Firefox textfields using `Shift+Insert` without having copied, so I'm not sure what you have configured differently.

Comment: In standard Ubuntu this doesn't work. Neither shell -> GUI app nor GUI app -> GUI app (Firefox, jEdit). Only shell -> shell.

Comment: My keyboard lacks an 'insert' key, so thanks for mentioning the ctrl-shift-v option.

Comment: `CTRL+SHIFT+C` and `CTRL+SHIFT+V` works for me as an alternative to highlight and middle click in Terminator shell on Ubuntu 16.10

Comment: Good luck trying to get ALT + C/ALT +V work too. I'm working with Linux under RealVNC on the Mac with a Mac keyboard so I want CMD + C/CMD +V to work to simulate the mac environment where those are the standard copy/paste keys, but even if I disable "Enable menu access keys) in Keyboard Shortcuts menu of the terminal app, it fails to work.

Answer (score 7):

Recipes for having a key perform the same action as a mouse middle-blick are given in the answers to [this AskUbuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7769/keyboard-shortcut-for-pasting-the-primary-selection).

(Although the question was asked on the [Ubuntu SE](http://askubuntu.com), there's nothing Ubuntu-specific in it: the solutions work on any X11 system.)