# Methods of pasting X11 primary selection contents?

Tags: x11, clipboard

I like having a keyboard shortcut to paste contents of X11 clipboard.  Right now, I have the following in my `.Xresources` file:

```
XTerm*VT100*translations: #override \n\
    <Key>F2: insert-selection(PRIMARY,CUT_BUFFER0)
```

That makes the  function key into a keyboard paste in an xterm window of whatever I've highlighted in some other xterm window.  I like having keyboard paste a special key on my left hand, because that means I can move the mouse around with my right hand, and I don't have to move from mouse-to-keyboard-and-back with my right hand all the time.

Does some more general method of doing this exist?  I'm stuck using explicit copy-n-paste (control-C, control-V) in Firefox, and I'd like to use  to paste everywhere.

Comment: Probably I misunderstand you, but I find the mouse's middle button handier: with the left mouse button (right hand) I select the text in Firefox, with Alt-Tab (left hand) I switch the window to XTerm, with middle button (right hand) I paste the text into XTerm. Have I missed something in your workflow?

Comment: Just a little.  If I copy some text with a mouse, I often want to paste it while both hands are back on the keyboard, you know, like when editing with Vim.  Or maybe I paste once with the middle-mouse-button, and then a few seconds later, I want to paste again, but both hands are on the keyboard.

Comment: Got it. Sorry, I have no idea that would better integrate into this workflow.

Comment: Do any of the answers to [these](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/11889/9537) [questions](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/15850/9537) work?

Answer (score 1):

You can map the execution of:

```
xte "mouseclick 2"
```

to some key or key combination in your window manager.

For instance, with openbox, add

```
<keybind key="S-F2">
    <action name="Execute">
      <command>xte "mouseclick 2"</command>
    </action>
</keybind>
```

to the keyboard section to bind it to <kbd>Shift-F2</kbd>