# Who stores copy/paste buffers in X11?

Tags: x11, clipboard

When a piece of text is highlighted with the mouse, it can be pasted by middle-clicking on the place you want, or by using the always classic `Shift+Insert` key combo.
But, when the area where that selected text is closed, the paste option is not valid, since the copied text is deleted.

Where is exactly the ready-to-paste text stored? Why is dependent on the application where you grab the text from instead to store that piece of text anywhere else, *e.g.*, in a place of the memory with no relation to the source of that highlighted text, and keep it there even when the application is closed or another text is selected?

Comment: Also, by selecting, you can paste with middle-clicking on most distros, however `Shift+Insert` won't work, for instance, on Debian 7 + gnome (it will paste from another clipboard). This is distro/GUI dependent apparently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In X, there will be one application which *owns* the current selection, which usually (but not always) is visible.  When you paste into an X client, that application *asks* the X server for the selection data, and the request is referred to the selection owner, who *provides* the information.

The selection owner may be capable of providing the selection data in more than one format.  For text, that may be UTF-8 (newer) or ISO-8859-1 (older).

Besides the *selection*, there are analogous transfers called *cut buffers*.  Those can be transferred whether or not an application currently owns the selection — but have more limited datatypes.

The ICCM ([Inter-Client Communication Conventions Manual](http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/xorg-docs/icccm/icccm.html)) documents this.  However, not all applications follow it (Netscape was a notable exception).

The clipboard is shared in a different way than X selections, and some people prefer that.  The clipboard is less dependent on who actually owns the data at a given moment.

xterm implements X selection, clipboard and cut-buffers using the X Toolkit.

For reference:

- [XtOwnSelection(3)](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.6/doc/man/man3/XtOwnSelection.3.xhtml)
- [xterm(1)](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html)
- [xclip(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xclip) - command line interface to X selections (clipboard)
- [xclipboard - X clipboard client](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/man/man1/xclipboard.1.html)
- [Gtk3 - Clipboards](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk3-Clipboards.html)
- [Pasting X selection (not clipboard contents) with keyboard](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11889/pasting-x-selection-not-clipboard-contents-with-keyboard)
- [How can I merge the gnome clipboard and the X selection?](https://superuser.com/questions/68170/how-can-i-merge-the-gnome-clipboard-and-the-x-selection%29.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but looks like you are talking about cut buffers.

For more info how clipboard and cut buffers works check out this links:

[freedesktop clipboards short spec](http://standards.freedesktop.org/clipboards-spec/clipboards-latest.txt),
[Inter-Client Communication Conventions Manual](http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/xorg-docs/icccm/icccm.html)
[X Selections, Cut Buffers, and Kill Rings](https://www.jwz.org/doc/x-cut-and-paste.html).

Happy digging!